# Changing `$ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME` in Run Script

Tags: xcode

I have different icons for different schemas in my Xcode project, I'm trying to change the AppIcon via `ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME` in a Run Script:

```
   #!/bin/bash

   $ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME="AppIcon"

   if [ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Staging" ];
   then
      $ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME="AppIconStaging"
   elif [ "$CONFIGURATION" == "Release" ];
   then
      $ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME="AppIconRelease"
   fi
```

The AssetCatalog's exist, but the icon's do not change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a build settings available under your targets:

It can be found under `Asset Catalog Compiler` > `Asset Catalog App Icon Name Set`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in your target's xcconfig:

```
ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME = $(ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME_$(CONFIGURATION))
ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME_ = AppIcon
ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME_Release = AppIconRelease
ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME_Staging = AppIconStaging
```

Comment: May I know what is $CONFIGURATION? And are we suppose to read from bottom up?  Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: My guess would be that he has the variable `CONFIGURATION` set via xcconfig in the target specific configs. The order doesn't matter